# Two overlapping oval shapes - visible artifacts

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have a square div with rounded corners. Inside this div, I need to make this shape:

[image: Example shape]

I want to do it with pure css, but there are two problems:

1. Little 1px green artifacts I can't get rid off (you can see them on the bottom and right sides)
2. I need a 1px red border around `#login_form` to also appear on top of my oval shapes.

Maybe there is a better way to cut the ovals.

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4x3ufg/) of the below:

```css
#login_form {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
}
#white_ovale {
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-border-radius: 225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px;
}
#green_ovale {
  position: absolute;
  right: -21px;
  bottom: -21px;
  width: 139px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 0px;
  background: #72B038;
  -webkit-border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px;
  border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
  box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="login_form">
  <div id="white_ovale"></div>
  <div id="green_ovale"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: FF and Ch shows really fine. What browser you're referring to?

Comment: Using an older version of Chrome and I can see the extra green extension that you refer to. Add a `overflow: hidden` maybe to the login_form and that should solve it.

Comment: 2Roko
I'm using Firefox 33.0

2Harry
Thank you, the overflow:hidden works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you need `overflow: hidden`
2. you need a 3rd inner div which adds the border (Just think of an independent border that stacks i top of the others)

BTW: Don't `id` everthing. Use classes. Use id only if you need to. And try not the nest ids.
As a rule of thumb I use only `class` for CSS and `id`for JS only

http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4x3ufg/1/

```css
.login_form {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    border:1px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.login_form .border {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.login_form .white_ovale {
 position: absolute;
 right: -10px;
 bottom: -10px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 80px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 
               225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px; 
    -moz-border-radius:
               225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px; 
    border-radius:
               225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px; 
}

.login_form .green_ovale {
 position: absolute;
 right:  -21px;
 bottom: -21px;
    width:  139px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 0px;
    background: #72B038;

    -webkit-border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px; 
       -moz-border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px; 
            border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px; 

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
         box-shadow: inset -10px -10px 0px 10px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="login_form">
    <div class="white_ovale"></div>
    <div class="green_ovale"></div>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! 
Very interesting solution for the border, I like it; I'follow your advice about classes -)

Comment: Here's how I rule out when to use `id`: if you have many elements which are alike (e.g. `<li>`in an `<ul>`) and you want to have a *single* one of them to behave different (whether CSS or JS doesn't matter), then you use `id` attribute. Or you may have several similar elements, which are interactive (e.g. YouTube videos) and which have to act via YouTube on some others, then use `id`.

Answer (score 1):

## Single element solution

There is no need for extra markup. We can create:

- the two shapes inside the div with `::before` and `::after`
- the red border with the containing div itself

The excess background is cut off with `overflow: hidden`

**Nice Advantage:** Because IE 8 does not support the `border-radius` property, and will render an ugly square, we can use the double colon (`::`) for the pseudo elements. [IE 8 does not recognise this syntax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) and will render just the red box. [This is the modern syntax and valid CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before).

**Note:** For child elements to overlap the green shape, they should be given `position: relative` and `z-index: 1`

**Browser Compatibility:**  [Due to the `border-radius` property, IE 9 +](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius). It is unlikely that you need the browser prefixes for the `border-radius` property.

### Complete Example

I have condensed the CSS as much as possible.

```css
.login_form {
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.login_form::before,
.login_form::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 80px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 225px 0px 7px 0px / 150px 0px 7px 0px;
}
.login_form::after {
  right: -31px;
  bottom: -21px;
  width: 149px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #72B038;
  border-radius: 225px 20px 7px 0px / 130px 0px 7px 0px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="login_form"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the reply. I'm using firefox and when I run your code I see white ovale like 30px upper from green one. Also the geometry is very different from the one I needed. I'm not sure is it a bug or no...

Comment: You're right @Desprit ! It was a result of me putting the border-radius property on a diet :) I have changed it back to the original border-radius values and it now looks great in Firefox.